# Am I out $200? (motherboard ceased booting)

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, troubleshooting

So, I was thrilled when I came home from Christmas with the parts for a compute node - a dual xeon board (S2600CP), two processors, fans, ram, PSU, etc. When I got home I tested the board outside the case, and after some work got it booting. Then I went to put it in my case, and discovered to my chagrin that I forgot to make sure that it would actually fit. So I went out shopping for a case that would fit, taking the board with to make sure it would actually fit. I ultimately purchased a case online. It got here today, I installed everything, with a lot of work, then turned it on.

CPU fans go on for one second, then shut off. Nothing else. No beep The motherboard's green "OK" LED doesn't change to amber or blink. No code LEDs come on. No fault indicator LEDs (ram, etc). It's just, on for a second, then back off. On the PSU side, the 5V is on all the time. When I turn on the computer, the 12V lights come on for a split second, then shut back off.

I tried to isolate it to a minimal case, taking everything out of the case, disconnecting nonessential hardware, etc. No change. All cables disconnected and reconnected. No change. I took an old PSU that I know was working. It's only 500W (vs. the new one with is 850) and only one CPU power connector, but I hooked it up. The behavior was exactly the same: the connected CPU's fan comes on for a second, then everything shuts off. No other indicators. I also tried a CMOS reset. No discernable effect.

Did my motherboard get fried somehow? :( I see no damage on it, for what little that's worth.....

The board was refurbished. Warrantied for 30 days, which expired last week while I was waiting for my case :(

Comment: Since it did not work with either PSU, it could definitely be the board. Before giving up entirely, take off both sides of the case and inspect if the motherboard is mounted correctly and it is not resting on something that is shorting it out. I also wonder how you handled the motherboard when you said you took it out with you.

Comment: Did you make sure to put the motherboard standoffs in the case before you turned screwed the motherboard into the case? This can cause issues like the one you are experiencing.

Comment: Removing the board from the case (and setting it on a piece of clean insulative foam for testing) was the first thing I tried.  My main guesses is that it was either handling while out (either from being in the car, or from fitting it into different cases, up to and including the one that ultimately arrived); or damage from a short from an improperly placed standoff.  Either way...